# Is ipyturtle missing much of the full turtle-graphics module?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, turtle-graphics, ipywidgets, python-turtle

I'm trying Turtle for the first time and running into some trouble. I'm using [ipyturtle](https://github.com/gkvoelkl/ipython-turtle-widget), a widget that lets you use Turtle inline on a Jupyter notebook. It seems to be missing some commands. For example:

```
from ipyturtle import Turtle
t = Turtle()
t

size = 10
angle = 20

t.reset()
for a in range(10):
    for i in range(100):
        t.right(1)
        t.forward(i/size)
    t.home()
    t.right(a*angle)
```

draws the first line, then throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'home'
```

It also seems to be missing `goto()`, `speed()`, among other key commands. Am I doing something wrong? If it is missing commands, how can you tell? I've used Python a fair amount in an engineering context but am unfamiliar with Github. I'd really appreciate an explanation of how someone navigating the page I linked above might sniff out a list of available commands.

I've tried running the following very similar block of code on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/) and it works fine:

```
from turtle import Turtle
t = Turtle()

size = 15
angle = 20

for a in range(1, 19):  
  for i in range(100):
    t.right(1)
    t.forward(i/size)
  t.home()
  t.right(a*angle)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the ipyturtle code, these are the turle methods supported:

```
position(self)
forward(self, length)
back(self, length)
heading(self)
goto(self, x, y=None)
setpos(self, x, y=None)
setposition(self, x, y=None)
left(self, degree=None)
right(self, degree=None)
penup(self)
pendown(self)
isdown(self)
hideturtle(self)
showturtle(self)
isvisible(self)
reset(self)
pencolor(self,r=-1,g=-1,b=-1)
```

So you're right about `home()` and `speed()` but `goto()` *does* appear to be there.  There also appears to be only one name for each command, not the wealth of aliases available in Python turtle (e.g. `forward()`, `fd()`).

The `t.home()` call can be replaced by:

```
t.goto(0, 0)
t.setheading(0)
```

But in your example, you immediately do `right()` afterward so we can combine that into the `setheading()`.  I believe the following should work in ipyturtle,  Repl.it and standard Python:

```
from turtle import Turtle

size = 10
angle = 20

t = Turtle()

for a in range(1, 19):
    for i in range(100):
        t.right(1)
        t.forward(i / size)
    t.goto(0, 0)
    t.setheading(-a * angle)
```

Comment: Thanks! Where did you find that list? I'd like to know where to look for things like that in the future.

Comment: Incidentally, `goto()` doesn't work on my installation; it yields the same attribute error I quoted in the original question.

Comment: @IanCanfield, try `setposition()` instead as it appears to be an alias for `goto()`.

Comment: `setposition()` and `setpos()` don't work either. At this point, I'm going to abandon ipyturtle and will use another solution. Thanks for your help anyways!